# How to get the name of an excel sheet after uploading an excel file using a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am currently uploading an excel file that contains one sheet and I would like to know how I can extract the name of the sheet.

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/BulkUpload" target="dummyframe" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
    <div></div>
    <div id="inputLabel">
        <input id="fileinput" name="image1" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
            <span>upload file</span>
            <input id="submitButton" class="submit" type="submit" value="ok" @*onclick="setTimeout(clearLabel,3000)"*@ />
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Totally depends on what server-side platform you're using.

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of the sheet on the client or the server after uploading? If the latter you need to show your C# code, and retag the question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the simplest way was to get the user to enter the name of the sheet on which processing must be done. In the event that the user does not enter a sheet name I default to a hardcoded sheet name in order to run my stored procedure.